# How to enable the image classification tool in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, classification, image-classification, toolbox

I intend to perform a supervised classification on a TIFF image in ArcGIS 10.8. The image is an imagery of an area which I downloaded from my ArcGIS Online account. The goal is to automatically extract footpaths from this imagery as it is a rural settlement. I've not performed any edits on the image whether on symbology or bands after importation. I've enabled the Spatial Analyst tool but every option in the drop-down menu of the image classification tool is still disabled. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have enabled the Spatial Analyst Extension from the Customize Options, and have selected the imagery layer in table of content.

https://youtu.be/aFTif12Ipf4